# Databricks cannot run import net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.Utils

Tags: databricks, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to run `Utils.runQuery(connection, "create table test_to_delete")`.

However the import statement cannot pass.

The documentation says I don't need any installation.

Comment: Can you post the error message that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "**import net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.Utils**" before you execute this command.

**Connecting to the Snowflake using Azure Databricks:**

[image]

**Create a table named adult in SnowFlake using ADB:**

[image]

**Successfully able to connect and create a table using SnowFlake using Azure Databricks:**

[image]

**[Snowflake Connector Tutorial](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/snowflake-demo.html):**

This tutorial walks through best practices for using the Snowflake-Databricks connector. In this tutorial we write data to Snowflake, use Snowflake for some basic data manipulation, train a machine learning model in Databricks, and output the results back to Snowflake.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.